# Restrict access to special AD groups for certain Angular routes with IIS10

Tags: angular, iis-10

I have a question whether or not it's possible to limit user access to a special AD group for certain route by using IIS?

So far I was able to limit the access for the whole app via the location tag and enable authorization for certain groups in my web.config on IIS10.

```
<location>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <clear />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="mydomain/group, mydomain/group2" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Now I want to limit the access to the /admin route defined in Angular, accessible under hostdomain/admin to only one group. But it won't work when I use  and just the one group. I assume because path in Angular routes is a virtual path while the path in the location tag is meant to be a physical folder on the disk.

```
<location path="admin">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <clear />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="mydomain/group2" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Is there any way to accomplish restricted access to the /admin route in IIS or would I need to add a middleware in my ExpressJS backend and make a call to call to the AD, get all the user groups for the autheticated user, filter for the specific group and restrict the access manually in ExpressJS and Angular?

Comment: I ended up splitting the ExpressJS backend in 2 parts, one for all users and one for the admins. If somebody has a better idea please let me know.